# Calculate t-test statistic for each group in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby

Given a `pandas` `DataFrame` with columns for `group`, `x`, and `y` (multiple records per `group` value), I'd like to create a new `DataFrame` with one row per `group` and the associated t-statistic for `x` and `y` values in that group. I'd like to do this with `groupby`, not a loop.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

N = 100  # Observations per group.
tt_df = pd.DataFrame({'group': np.append(['A'] * N, ['B'] * N),
                      'x': np.random.randn(2 * N)})
tt_df['y'] = tt_df['x'] + np.random.randn(2 * N)
stats.ttest_ind(tt_df['x'], tt_df['y'])[0]  # -0.32 global t statistic.
```

Answer (score 6):

```
tt_df.groupby('group').apply(lambda df: stats.ttest_ind(df['x'], df['y'])[0])
# group
# A   -0.292413
# B   -0.167816
# dtype: float64
```